# IDE output different from command line

Tags: java, command-line, ide, output

I've wrote a programme to mask the input that a user types in at the command line.
In detail:
When my programme starts, I run a new thread that prints out an asterisk every millisecond via               System.out.print("\010*").
Meanwhile my main method reads in the users input via read.nextLine().

When I run this programme in eclipse, the output is an overflow of asterisks (which is what I would expect).
However, when I run this programme from my terminal, I only see an asterisk appear whenever I type a character.

Why is this? I read some other articles saying how the CPU only allocates 6-10% of memory to the command line, whereas a typical IDE gets more than twice this.

My code is shown below just for reference:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String [] args){

    PasswordMasker passwordMasker = new PasswordMasker();
    passwordMasker.start();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String password = scan.nextLine();

    passwordMasker.stopMasking();

    System.out.println("The password is: " + password);

   }
}



public class PasswordMasker extends Thread {

private boolean maskInProgress = true;

   public void run(){
        mask();
   }

   private void mask() {
      while(maskInProgress){
         try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
             System.out.print("\010*");
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }  
      }
      System.out.println("Masking stopped");
   }

   public void stopMasking(){
      this.maskInProgress = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? On what operating system? I just compiled your code using Eclipse under windows, and, after slowing down the delay to 100ms, and removing the "\010" it works fine, both in the IDE and from a DOS command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Eclipse console can't display backspace character (\b or \010),
because of bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936

The cmd can display it, that is why your program works as expected in cmd.

However the fix will be available in Eclipse 4.5 M4, according to the bug report.